# Bind value directly to JSF selectItem without p:selectManyCheckbox value

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, nested

So it's like this.

MyMb:

```java
@Named("MyMb")
@SessionScoped
public class MySuperCoolMb implements Serializable {
    //Tons of attributes

    private List<ListModelOne> lmo = new ArrayList();

    //Tons of methods
}
```

Outter Model:

```java
public class ListModelOne {

    private coolObject object;
    private List<ReadWrite> permissions;

    //init()
    //setters-getters

}
```

Inner Model, this is the Model that needs to be bind directly to the selectItems on screen

```java
public class ReadWrite {

    private String accessItem;
    private boolean read = false;
    private boolean write = false;
    //Somewhere in my code i change this from true/false depending
    //what i need and they do change in title in xhtml.
    //setters-getters
}
```

And my xhtml:

```xhtml
<h3>Cool Title</h3>
<p:accordionPanel value="#{MyMb.lmo}" var="modelOne">
    <p:tab title="#{modelOne.coolObject.ObjectName}">
    <h3>Cool Inner Title</h3>
        <ui:repeat value="#{modelOne.permissions}" var="readWrite">
            <h:panelGrid>
            <h:outputText value="#{readWrite.accessItem}"/>
                <!-- selectManyCheckbox has no value attribute because i don't need/have a list/collection to bind it -->
                <p:selectManyCheckbox>
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Read" itemValue="#{readWrite.read}" title="This is set to #{readWrite.read}"/>
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Write" itemValue="#{readWrite.write}" title="This is set to #{readWrite.write}"/>
                </p:selectManyCheckbox>
            </h:panelGrid>
        </ui:repeat>
    </p:tab>
</p:accordionPanel>
```

Everything works fine but the checkboxes (selectItem), can they be bound directly to an attribute of a class and ignote value of p:selectManyCheckboxes?
Everything works fine on java, i've debugged and the values are right, they even print OK on "tittle" attribute in the f:selectItem (Some true, and some false)

PS: Also i couldn't understand the difference between ItemLabel, label, ItemValue, Value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does anything aspect against using two `<p:selectBooleanCheckbox>`?

Otherwise I'd propose a code like this:

```
<h:panelGrid>
    <h:outputText value="#{readWrite.accessItem}"/>
    <p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="Read" itemLabel="#{readWrite.read}" />
    <p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="Write" itemLabel="#{readWrite.write}" />
</h:panelGrid>
```

Look at this: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/booleanCheckbox.xhtml

ItemValue and ItemLabel are used if you want to dynamically generate your selectOptions (like checkboxes or options in a dropdown-menu etc). 
Example:

```
// Java-class...
@Named(
public enum SelectOption(){
    Max, Oliver, John;
}

// In bean...
private List<SelectOption> fornames; // with setter & getter

// In xhtml...
<p:selectManyCheckbox value="#{bean.fornames}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{bean.fornames.values()}" var="forname" 
        itemValue="#{forname}" itemLabel="#{forname.toString()}" />
</p:selectManyCheckbox>
```

Explanation: the List in your bean will get all selected items. The `f:selectItems`-tag takes all possible options from the enumeration (you can hand over any collection), and iterates over every "forname"-object in the collection. In this case, the itemValue represents itself as we have a list of that object to save it in, and for the label, we call the toString-Method.

I hope this is explained understandable.

Comment: Yes, that's the answer, i did this yesterday but it's still not working, somehow when i open the p:tab, primefaces goes to the setters ONLY OF THE CHECKBOXES and set them to false. (Not to the setter of the String accessItem on my class ReadWrite)
But that's another issue, maybe i'll open another question.

Comment: Well... i erased it from the code above, but i had Dynamic=true on acordeonPanel, so the lazy loading was doing some strange things. Still tyvm for taking your time. Cheers

Comment: The lazy loading feature is nice in theory, but doesn't work well with too many events, ajax and so on...
I dont get what you want to do with the setter of accessItem. In your code, the attribute is read only (by the output-text). Please Tell me, if you have further issues. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

the difference between itemlabel and ItemValue is that itemlabel is the label displayed and ItemValue is the value given to selecting